# HTML5 Canvas getContext issue

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a 2D canvas with a image on it but I keep getting the following error about getContext...

*Unhandled exception at line 9, column 1 in //localhost:50400/Scripts/game.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'getContext' of undefined or null reference*

I'm not sure where to go from here...

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="gameCnavas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/game.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

### JS

```
/// <reference path="jquery-2.1.1.js" />

var canvasWidth = 800;
var canvasHeight = 600;

$('gameCanvas').attr('width', canvasWidth);
$('gameCanvas').attr('height', canvasHeight);

var canvas = $('#gameCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');

canvas.strokeRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

var image = new Image();
image.src = "ship.png";

$(image).load(function () {
    canvas.drawImage(image, (canvasWidth * .5) - (image.width * .5),
        (canvasHeight * .5) - (image.height * .5));
});
```

Comment: You have a misspelling in the canvas id, is 'gameCanvas' instead of 'gameCnavas'

Comment: You should check the console for errors next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in your code.

In your HTML code you wrote the id as "gameCnavas":

```
<canvas id="gameCnavas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

But the id you are referencing in your script is "gameCanvas":

```
var canvas = $('#gameCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');
```

In other words the Id's do not match which is why you're getting the Null reference error.

Answer (score 1):

Change your canvas object id from...

```
<canvas id="gameCnavas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

to...

```
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```